# GeoServer connection to PostGIS - Unable to find 'factory store'?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, geoserver-app-schema

I have a problem with a database connection on GeoServer.

I have installed the app-schema plugin.

In my workspace, named `nc`, I would like to connect to postgres (on localhost) to a target table `p_giunzione_stradale` on db `progetto`.

But when I start the GeoServer I have this warning:

```
WARN [geoserver.security] - Could not find factory store : DataStoreInfoImpl[nc_giunzione_stradale]. Unable to encrypt connection parameters
```

The PostGIS extension is installed correctly and the system user is the same as the db user, and owner of the database 'progetto'. Moreover psql console is accessible without password from the shell.

The connection parameters are stored in `nc_giunzione_stradale.xml` file located in the directory `workspaces/nc/nc_giunzione_stradale` as requested by app-schema.

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

I attach the content of nc_giunzione_stradale.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<as:AppSchemaDataAccess xmlns:as="http://www.geotools.org/app-schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.geotools.org/app-schema AppSchemaDataAccess.xsd">
    <namespaces>
        <Namespace>
                <prefix>nc</prefix>
            <uri>urn:nc</uri>
        </Namespace>
        <Namespace>
            <prefix>gml</prefix>
            <uri>http://www.opengis.net/gml</uri>
        </Namespace>
        <Namespace>
                <prefix>xlink</prefix>
            <uri>http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink</uri>
        </Namespace>
    </namespaces>
    <sourceDataStores>
        <DataStore>
            <id>datastoreNC</id>
            <parameters>
                <Parameter>
                    <name>dbtype</name>
                    <value>postgisng</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                    <name>host</name>
                    <value>localhost</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                    <name>port</name>
                    <value>5432</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                    <name>database</name>
                    <value>progetto</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                        <name>schema</name>
                        <value>public</name>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                    <name>user</name>
                    <value>michele</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                    <name>password</name>
                    <value>miapwd</value>
                </Parameter>
            </parameters>
        </DataStore>
    </sourceDataStores>
    <targetTypes>
        <FeatureType>
            <schemaUri>nc.xsd</schemaUri>
        </FeatureType>
    </targetTypes>
    <typeMappings>
        <FeatureTypeMapping>
            <sourceDataStore>datastoreNC</sourceDataStore>
            <sourceType>p_giunzione_stradale</sourceType>
            <targetElement>nc:Giunzione_stradale</targetElement>
            <attributeMappings>
                <AttributeMapping>
                    <targetAttribute>
                        nc:UUID
                    </targetAttribute>
                    <idExpression>
                        <OCQL>classid</OCQL>
                    </idExpression>
                </AttributeMapping>
                <AttributeMapping>
                    <targetAttribute>
                        nc:Posizione
                      </targetAttribute>
                    <sourceExpression>
                        <OCQL>posizione</OCQL>
                    </sourceExpression>
                </AttributeMapping>
            </attributeMappings>
        </FeatureTypeMapping>
    </typeMappings>
</as:AppSchemaDataAccess>
```

Comment: Show us the nc_giunzione_stradale.xml file contents?